# ACF - category field data to its containing posts/pages

Tags: categories, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I am trying to find a general way to bring the field data of a category to the posts in this category.

My categories have fields like "e-mail", "adress" etc. and I can show this data on the category pages. It would make sense that the posts/pages assigned to a category somehow inherit the field data of their parent category.

Is there a way to achieve this through functions.php or some setting?

Some help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Cheers, Markus

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you would have to do a separate query in the post/page template to get the acf field data associated with the category of the posts/pages.

You could make this into a function. You would send the categories from the template page for your posts or pages to this function and get the template to assemble the acf metadata.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. Initially I thought that category data would automatically be "connected" to the posts/pages.

You have any idea on how to achieve this?